# Why does a `docker run` command generate two distinct images when built?

Tags: docker

I made a simple Dockerfile which contains something like the following:

```
# Comment
FROM python:3.8.3

RUN pip install matplotlib
```

I then build this using the following command:

`docker build -f DockerFile .`

When I list the generated images using `docker image ls` the result is unexpected:

```
D:\TEMP\docker>docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              fcb250745fa1        2 minutes ago       1.06GB
python              3.8.3               7f5b6ccd03e9        6 weeks ago         934MB
```

Why are two images created as opposed to only one? Why does the top one have no repository or tag?

Comment: Two images are not created. That `python` image was pulled from dockerhub when docker was building your image (your FROM statement). And that `<none>` is the image you built (it shows as none because you didn't give it any tags). If you want to give it a name, use `-t` option (e.g. `-t myimage:mytag`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven’t provided a tag using -t, the image you created doesn’t have a name/tag.

The python image is listed because it’s implicitly downloaded for the build.

Comment: I understand why `python:3.8.3` is built, but what annoys me is being able to run it as its own container. I didn't specify in my DockerFile that I want it to become a runnable image...

Answer (score 1):

The `python` image is the image you pull from Docker Hub to be able to perform the build step, so this is not your image, but docker will save it in case you need it again.

You are building another layer on top of the `python` image with your Dockerfile and the result of that is the image you see as `<none>`.